# How to make sure all radiobox questions have been interacted with

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

A small app where user needs to select either Yes or No for each task. The user should NOT be allowed to leave the page unless they have answered all questions. I have added a button at the bottom of the form which simulates `beforeRouterLeave` behaviour.

My question is about the `simulateBeforeRouteLeave()` function. How can do I check if all questions have been answered to allow user to leave?

Ps. This is a snipped from a much larger project. The original data comes from a API and its NOT hard coded like in this example.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuejs-checkcompleted-wnzk0?file=/src/App.vue)

App.vue

```
<template>
  <parent-component
    v-for="task in tasks.data"
    :key="task.id"
    :taskData="task"
    @update-form-data="handleChange"
  >
  </parent-component>
  <button
    class="my-2 border-2 border-red-500"
    @click="simulateBeforeRouteLeave"
  >
    simulateBeforeRouteLeave
  </button>
</template>

<script>
import parentComponent from "./components/parentComponent.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    parentComponent,
  },
  methods: {
    simulateBeforeRouteLeave() {
      //Need HELP Here! How do I write this IF statement?
      if ("Options_NOT_Selected") {
        alert("Please select all options");
      } else {
        console.log("Allow user to leave 'next()'");
      }
    },
    handleChange(e) {
      const objIndex = this.tasks.data.findIndex((obj) => obj.id === e.id);
      this.tasks.data[objIndex].status = e.status;
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      markAll: false,
      tasks: {
        data: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: "Task 1",
            status: null,
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: "Task 2",
            status: null,
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            name: "Task 3",
            status: null,
          },
        ],
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

parentComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="py-2">
    <div>
      <input
        type="radio"
        :id="taskData.id + 'Yes'"
        :name="taskData.name"
        :value="taskData.value"
        @change="updateData"
      />
      <label :for="taskData.id">{{ taskData.name }} Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input
        type="radio"
        :id="taskData.id + 'No'"
        :name="taskData.name"
        :value="taskData.value"
      />
      <label :for="taskData.id">{{ taskData.name }} No</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["taskData"],
  methods: {
    updateData(e) {
      this.$emit("update-form-data", {
        id: this.taskData.id,
        status: 1,
      });
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
};
</script>
```